# What is the best color scale to display data with wide range but skewed to the right?

Tags: data-visualization

I want to visualize some data (for example I could use a heatmap or a choropletic map) using color.

These data have domain `[0, 100]` but are crushed to the left, so most of them are in the range `[0, 25]`.

Here is part of my dataset:

[image]

I have very large dataset, those numbers in the picture are only a very small part.

Which is the best color scale I can use to display them correctly?

The linear scale obviously doesn't work.

---

For example, if I had this data:

var data = [2, 3, 6, 1, 0.5, 2, 80, 1, 1.2, 4, 1, 0.7, 0.1, 2.3, 3];

I could use the linear scale, the power scale or the quantile scale and get these results:

[image]

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/boYj03nbxkSDRqB0bFw5?p=preview)**

The problem is obvious, none of the three scales work as I would like.
We can not clearly distinguish the differences between the data.
I would also like to use the Viridis color scale and I don't know how to do it.

Any help?

Comment: Sorry, but it is isn't obvious what you would like. Also, as your values aren't in order, it is hard work to compare your schemes. In all cases you're using a very narrow range of colours, so perhaps you need to change that.

Comment: Strictly, you have right skewed data, not left skewed. Whether it is right or left is a matter of which is the longer tail (as viewed e.g. on a conventional histogram).

Comment: Plot a histogram and assign the colors manually based on whatever features you want to distinguish. another thing, why not give us an example with the real data and with the viridis color scale instead of the red tones? I do not really know what direction you should go if you are not able to distinguish the differences in the data (what differences do you wish to see? and how does it look like now? people that come across your question do not know these things based on the information that you give).

Answer (score 2):

The quantile scale looks like it is working but you could choose better colors. When you have to color code something that goes low to high, you want the scale to have a natural "low" and "high".  Going from black to red (as you are doing) doesn't do this.  You could go from white to black or from a very pale pink to a very saturated red.

You want what is called a "sequential palette" in [this paper](https://eeecon.uibk.ac.at/~zeileis/papers/Zeileis+Hornik+Murrell-2009.pdf) by Zeileis, Hornik and Murrell.